# How can I obtain key and value of a hash in Jekyll / liquid?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll page with the following setup:

```
---
navigation:
 - FOO: foo
 - BAR: bar
 - BAZ: baz
---

<h3>
  <a name="{{ page.navigation[0][1] }}" class="anchor" 
     href="#{{ page.navigation[0][1] }}">
  </a>{{ page.navigation[0][0] }}
</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</p>

...

<h3>
  <a name="{{ page.navigation[1][1] }}" class="anchor" 
     href="#{{ page.navigation[1][1] }}">
  </a>{{ page.navigation[1][0] }}
</h3>

<p>Different content ...</p>

...

<h3>
  <a name="{{ page.navigation[2][1] }}" class="anchor" 
     href="#{{ page.navigation[2][1] }}">
  </a>{{ page.navigation[2][0] }}
</h3>

<p>Another different content ...</p>

...
```

I am trying to use the `key` and `value` of each navigation item in my front matter with the `href` links in the example above.

I can not use `{% for %}` iterations because inside each paragraph is a different content.

**My desire is to have Jekyll output the following code:**

```
<h3>
  <a name="foo" class="anchor" href="#foo">
  </a>FOO
</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</p>

...

<h3>
  <a name="bar" class="anchor" href="#bar">
  </a>BAR
</h3>

<p>Different content ...</p>

...

<h3>
  <a name="baz" class="anchor" href="#baz">
  </a>BAZ
</h3>

<p>Another different content</p>

...
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could warp a for loop around each item in navigation like this:

```
<h3>
    {% for item in page.navigation[0] %}
     <a name="{{ item[1] }}" class="anchor" 
        href="#{{ item[1] }}">
     </a>{{ item[0] }}
     {% endfor %}
</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</p>

<h3>
    {% for item in page.navigation[1] %}
     <a name="{{ item[1] }}" class="anchor" 
        href="#{{ item[1] }}">
     </a>{{ item[0] }}
     {% endfor %}
    </h3>

<p>Different content ...</p>


<h3>
    {% for item in page.navigation[2] %}
     <a name="{{ item[1] }}" class="anchor" 
        href="#{{ item[1] }}">
     </a>{{ item[0] }}
     {% endfor %}
    </h3>

<p>Another different content</p>
```